# What is citation_key in BibTeX notation?

Tags: bibtex, citing

What is citation_key in BibTeX notation:

@ARTICLE{citation_key,
              required_fields [, optional_fields] }

We have many articles written by our academic staff on our website.We want to put the BibTeX citation for each of articles . can i use the article id as citation_key ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The citation key is the abbreviation the user has to input when using the `\cite{...}` command. It can be almost anything you want it to be (letters, numbers, dashes, underscores -- I'd avoid other punctuation), but if you're preparing something for others to use, it's best to make it something that a user would find easy to remember. Common styles are author-year or author-shorttitle, e.g., `knuth-texbook` or `knuth1984`. I wouldn't make a citation key consist only of numbers -- that's too hard to remember.